# Jquery send form POST change value of inputs if collapse = false

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Hi i'm trying to make a validation on my form and change the **values** that send through form if a collapse element(of that value) = False to a null value (i'm still kinda new to javascript and Jquery).

```js
if (document.getElementById("filter_form")) {
    var slider1 = document.getElementById("price_min");
    var slider2 = document.getElementById("price_max");
    
    output1.value = slider1.value; // Display the default slider value
    output2.value = slider2.value;

    output1.oninput = function() {
        slider1.value = this.value;
    }
    output2.oninput = function() {
        slider2.value = this.value;
    }
    // Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
    slider1.oninput = function() {
        output1.value = this.value;
    }
    slider2.oninput = function() {
        output2.value = this.value;
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').click(function(event) {
    if ($('#price').attr("aria-expanded") == "true") {
      var price_min = Number($('#price_min').val());
      var price_max = Number($('#price_max').val());
    } else {
      var price_min = null;
      var price_max = null;
      $('#price_min').value = null;
      $('#price_max').value = null;
    }
    if (price_min > price_max) {
      event.preventDefault();
      iziToast.warning({
        title: 'Fail!',
        message: 'min price cant be larger than max price',
        position: 'bottomRight'
      }); //my alert
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/izitoast/1.4.0/js/iziToast.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="/search_url/'">
  <div class="form-group">
    <p>
      <button id="price" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample-1" style="width: 100%">
                  Price
                </button>
    </p>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-1">
      <div>Min: <input type="number" id="price_min_value" min="0" max="100000000000" value="0" /></div>
      <input type="range" id="price_min" class="form-control" min="0" max="100000000000" value="0" name="price_min">
      <div>Max: <input type="number" id="price_max_value" min="0" max="100000000000" value="100000000000" /></div>
      <input type="range" id="price_max" class="form-control" min="0" max="100000000000" value="100000000000" name="price_max">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary mr-1" id="search">Search</button>
</form>
```

On the server when i received the data from POST request with collapse flase, i got price_min = '0' and price_max ='100000000000'

**Expected results:**

It should be price_min = null and price_max = null

I don't know why it doesn't set the POST data equal **NULL**, and i don't know why.

**EDIT:**

ok this is weird when i change my set value code to:

```
$('#price_min').val("");
$('#price_max').val("");
```

and send the form post it return server to the value equal to the middle value of the range input(50000000000), but when i tried to do this:

```
$('#price_min').val("1234");
$('#price_max').val("12345");
```

and on the server i actually got the changed value of price_min = 1234 and price_max = 12345

why does this work? but when i try to set it value or null or none it doesn't work and just take the middle value of the range input?

I'm so confused

Thank for reading

Comment: try posting your form using ajax that we you can change the data and the same will be posted to server

Comment: I tried that but the page doesn't change,  The function from the server that this is a search button so it should change the page when call the url with POST

Comment: that you can do once you have got a successful response from the server.

Comment: yeah but the page changing should be handle by the server since it carry out data to the page too. Im using django on the backend side

Comment: Not sure how is your application structured? is it server driven or is it a client side application?

Comment: server driven, but i only want to use jquery to pop out alert if input is wrong( and prevent form sending) and change the value if collapsed, which i can only check on html with jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting value with `.value` but in jQuery we use `.val()` and set value as 0 instead of null as number type input does not accept null. Change the logic at server side to check if value is 0 instead of null.

Also, use `preventDefault` as first line in the search button click so that button will not submit the form directly.

See below code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // it will prevent default behavior of button clicked
    console.log('button clicked');
    if ($('#price').attr("aria-expanded") == "true") {
      var price_min = new Number($('#price_min').val());
      var price_max = new Number($('#price_max').val());
    } else {
      var price_min = 0;
      var price_max = 0;
      $('#price_min').val(price_min);
      $('#price_max').val(price_max);
    }
    if (price_min > price_max) {
      iziToast.warning({
        title: 'Fail!',
        message: 'min price cant be larger than max price',
        position: 'bottomRight'
      }); //my alert
    } else {
      $("#searchForm").submit();
   }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/izitoast/1.4.0/js/iziToast.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="/search_url/'" id="searchForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <p>
      <button id="price" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample-1" style="width: 100%">
                  Price
                </button>
    </p>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-1">
      <div>Min: <input type="number" id="price_min_value" min="0" max="100000000000" value="0" /></div>
      <input type="range" id="price_min" class="form-control" min="0" max="100000000000" value="0" name="price_min">
      <div>Max: <input type="number" id="price_max_value" min="0" max="100000000000" value="100000000000" /></div>
      <input type="range" id="price_max" class="form-control" min="0" max="100000000000" value="100000000000" name="price_max">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary mr-1" id="search">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i also tried using val() but when i get result on back end with request.POST.get("price_min") = "0" and request.POST.get("price_max") = "100000000000"

Comment: Please check my updated post where you need to use preventDefault as first line in the click event handler so that button will not submit form directly without running your jquery script.

Comment: But now my form wont submit

Comment: You need to submit it externally using `$("#searchForm").submit();` where searchForm is the id of the form element in html

Comment: i had made an update to my question include a script i use to set the number from number input the same as the range slider, maybe that the problem but still haven't figure it out

Comment: i think it has something to do with the range input unable to set value equal null with the jquery val() function, but other value beside null worked

Comment: it is a number field so the default value can be 0 instead of null and hence it is not getting set with jquery. Try to set 0 and change the logic at server side

Comment: yeah that was the problem i set both equal 0 if its collapse and check on server if both value equal 0 , if it's then set price_min and price_max = None, thank you, i didn't know that value null doesn't work on input type = range